# Defining "advance" has-one-of-many relationship that retrieve the last (of many) record made by user with specific role

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Assume that I have `Post` model that stores any "post" created by users, and `PostLog` models that stores the changes log of a `Post` model. Obviously, the `Post` is having `hasMany()` relation to `PostLog`.

Now I want to define a has-one-of-many out of that relation. The `PostLog` has `user_id` which define the user who makes the changes. I want to retrieve the latest `PostLog` created by users with a specific role.

Regarding to the `users` and `roles` table, their relation is established as many-to-many, meaning that there's `role_user` that connects the two of them.

This is the best that I came up with, but I'm not getting the correct value (obviously):

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    public function latestAdminPostLog()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PostLog::class)->ofMany([
            'id' => 'max',
            'created_at' => 'max'
        ], function ($query) {
            $query->whereExists(function ($qry) {
                $qry->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('users')
                    ->join('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
                    ->join('roles', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
                    ->whereColumn('users.id', 'post_logs.user_id')
                    ->whereIn('roles.name', ['admin-x', 'admin-y']);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Your help is much appeciated. Thanks!

Note: I'm using [santigarcor/laratrust](https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust) package for the user-role management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do

```php
public function latestAdminPostLog(){
     return $this->hasOne(PostLog::class)->whereHas('user', fn (Builder $query) => $query->whereRoleIs(['admin-x', 'admin-y']))->latest();
}
```

this returns latest PostLog that was created by a user that has admin-x or admin-y role

have a nice day

Comment: This is surprisingly working. How could you know that `whereHas()` can be chained after `hasOne()` ? The docs didn't mention any of it. Can you provide a link or something that I can read to?

Comment: these are all query builders and return what you were doing, laravel is not magic, try toSql() function sometimes you get the hang of it.